# Why can't I stop my Mojo app using systemd?

Tags: perl, systemd, mojolicious

I can fire up my Mojo app via `systemd` without any issues, but I can't stop or restart it in the same way.  I've poached my config mostly from the Mojo docs at http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Pre-forking:

```
[Unit]
Description=ldsquiz.org
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
ExecStart=/home/sites/www.ldsquiz.org/checkout/bin/carton-exec app.pl prefork -m production -l http://*:5103
KillMode=process
User=ldsquiz
Group=ldsquiz
SyslogIdentifier=ldsquiz-org

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I stop it via `sudo service ldsquiz-org stop` then syslog says `Jan 13 16:37:48 web-hosting systemd[1]: Stopped ldsquiz.org.` but the processes are still running.

A `restart` via `systemd` looks like I would expect, since the listen socket is still in use because of the failed shutdown:

```
Jan 13 16:39:13 web-hosting systemd[1]: Stopped ldsquiz.org.
Jan 13 16:39:13 web-hosting systemd[1]: Started ldsquiz.org.
Jan 13 16:39:14 web-hosting ldsquiz-org[20353]: Can't create listen socket: Address already in use at 
/home/sites/www.ldsquiz.org/checkout/local/lib/perl5/Mojo/IOLoop.pm line 126.
Jan 13 16:39:14 web-hosting systemd[1]: ldsquiz-org.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=98/n/a
Jan 13 16:39:14 web-hosting systemd[1]: ldsquiz-org.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 13 16:39:14 web-hosting systemd[1]: ldsquiz-org.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 13 16:39:15 web-hosting ldsquiz-org[16886]: [Sat Jan 13 16:39:15 2018] [info] Creating process id file "/tmp/prefork.pid"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I usually control my `systemd` units with `systemctl start/stop/status/restart $serviceName`. Does that make any difference? I.e. `systemctl stop ldsquiz-org`?

Comment: @PerlDuck that seems to have the same problem for me. It thinks that the app has been stopped but the original processes are still hanging around.

Comment: I know the docs you refer to say `Type=simple` but this `prefork` parameter makes me doubt. Perhaps give `Type=forking` a try. See [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) for the possible values. Perhaps you also need to play a bit with the `KillMode=` setting. See [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode=) for the possible values. And remember to call `systemctl daemon-reload` whenever you fiddle with the unit file.

Comment: @PerlDuckwonderful! `KillMode=control-group` did the trick for me. Looks like I'll need to see about a Mojo doc patch.  If you'd like to write an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: As an addendum, this issue has now been addressed in the Mojo docs: https://github.com/kraih/mojo/commit/393daba639d1a4d3f3c07c4094425a35a78889ca

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently there's a flaw in the *Mojolicious Cookbook* w.r.t. preforking and systemd units.

[They say](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Pre-forking):

> And to manage the pre-forking web server with systemd, you can use a
>   unit configuration file like this.
>
> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=My Mojolicious application
> After=network.target
>
> [Service]
> Type=simple
> ExecStart=/home/sri/myapp/script/my_app prefork -m production -l http://*:8080
> KillMode=process
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

The `KillMode=process` setting turns out to be wrong and needs to be replaced with `KillMode=control-group` — which is the default setting, so we can drop it altogether.

The [KillMode docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode=) say:

> **If set to `control-group`, all remaining processes** in the control group
>   of this unit **will be killed** on unit stop (for services: after the stop
>   command is executed, as configured with ExecStop=). **If set to
>   `process`, only the main process itself is killed.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Thus:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Mojolicious application
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/sri/myapp/script/my_app prefork -m production -l http://*:8080
KillMode=control-group

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that the `KillMode=control-group` can be omitted as this setting is the default.

References:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode=
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=

Comment: Yes. That "KillMode" setting has since been removed from the example docs: https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/pull/1183